# unable to resolve dot net core version - visual studio

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api

I am facing this error since I restarted the system. I am not sure what went wrong.
I have restarted my system many times. Please help.

[image]

Comment: Did this error message appear after you restarted the project? Have your try to `clean and reBuild` the project or restart the visual studio?

Comment: @XinranShen .. Thank you for comment. I tried it already but its not working.. getting same error again and again.

Comment: When something goes wrong in VS (and it does some times) - with VS closed, delete the project's `.vs`, `bin` and `obj` folders (they will be recreated).

Comment: @Neeraj Singh Chouhan, Sorry, Just this error message is hard to find the issue.

Answer (score 1):

Is this happening when you open a solution / project or when you just open visual studio with a blank solution ?

You could try deleting your global.json file (or rename it so you have a backup), that should ensure you use the latest sdk installed.

If that does not work, try running

```
dotnet --list-sdks
```

and

```
dotnet --list-runtimes
```

and update your question with the info.

If you want to run a specific SDK version, post your global.json as well.

Answer (score 0):

Either your dot net core installation has a problem, or the project settings are messed up.

Based on my experience, you should do the following (in order, in case one step doesn't work, go to the next one).

1. Create an empty dot net core project and print something. If it works, then your dot net core installation is correct.
2. Check the project settings (right click on the project, properties). Check that it has the correct dot net version. Are you sure it was originally a dot net core project and not a dot net framework? Change it to the correct version if necessary.
3. If nothing works, create a new project with the same dot net core version as the one you did in Step 1, and copy your files. Sometimes Visual Studio settings get messed up inside a project.

Hope this helps!

Comment: I created test app with same version and its working fine. But my current project still giving same error.

Comment: Then the problem are your settings. Did you try step 2? If it doesn't work, then re-create the project. Sometimes is easier and faster to create a new project and copy all the files, than messing up with the settings.

Answer (score 0):

In control panel I could see there are some more .NET core SDK and runtime version were installed along with my project version 3. I uninstall other SDKand runtime and error went away. thanks everyone for help.